# Ubuntu Server 20.04 Installer: Can't select disk (4GB Disk)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

I am attempting to install Ubuntu Server 20.04 on a 4GB CFast Card, but the Installer does not allow me to select the disk.

The disk itself is connected via a USB Adapter.

[The disk itself is grayed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLY0B.jpg)

The documentation states that 2GB should be enough for the installation.

Comment: Linux can't be installed on a disk, only on a partition.